# How to create a new object and set layout_centerVertical to true programatically?

Tags: android

I'm creating an ImageView programatically and I want to set layout_centerVertical="true" and android:layout_centerHorizontal="true".

I tried this code:

```
    ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
    Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
    myImage.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier((card.getColor() + "_" + card.getFigure()).toLowerCase(), "drawable", this.getPackageName()));
    myImage.setTag(IMAGEVIEW_TAG);

    myImage.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.toplinear);
    layout.addView(myImage);

    View positiveButton = myImage.getRootView();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)positiveButton.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    positiveButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

However logcat throws an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.addRule(int,
>   int)' on a null object reference
>               at pl.ds13ds14.ucp.CardsActivity.AddCard(CardsActivity.java:55)

The line 55 contains:

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

Comment: so what is unclear? the error description tells it all...

Comment: Why is it null? How to set these values correctly?

Comment: "This method may return null if this View is not attached to a parent ViewGroup or setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams) was not invoked successfully. When a View is attached to a parent ViewGroup, this method must not return null."

Comment: I bother with this for hours. Could you give me some example code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

---

```
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.toplinear);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    myImage.setLayoutParams(params);
    layout.addView(myImage, params);
```